# Javascript is giving me an error when there isn't any

Tags: javascript, syntax, undefined

This piece of code was working fine, now i'm always getting a "unexpected token else"

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.search("url=") == 0){
            $("#showMessage").after('<div class="message"><center>Copy your new URL:<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="'+xmlhttp.responseText.substr(4)+'"</input><br /></center></div>');
        else{   
            $("#showMessage").after('<div class="error">'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

This is what calls it:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:createURL()"/>
```

(i'm also getting a "createURL is not defined", but i'm guessing that's because of the syntax error)

Answer (score 2):

You need a closing bracket before your `else`.

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText.search("url=") == 0){
   $("#showMessage").after('<div class="message"><center>Copy your new URL:<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="'+xmlhttp.responseText.substr(4)+'"</input><br /></center></div>');
} else{   
    $("#showMessage").after('<div class="error">'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</div>');
}
```

Comment: whoops! guess i need a second pair of eyes, haha, thanks man.

Comment: @user1925957 No problem. We've all been there before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the `if ... else` statement

Right now it is:

```
if(){
...
//<< There should be a closing bracket for the if statement here
else{
...
}
```

But it should be:

```
if(){
...
}
else{
...
}
```

or you can skip the brackets if the code in the `if` or `else` clause is on one line:

```
if() ...;
else ...;
```